# Implementing push-like technology

Tags: java, android, client-server

I want to be able to exchange data between my app and the server where each side has to be able to initiate sending of data. I want it to happen quickly and polling from the client side for new messages is not fast enough in my case. How do push technologies work?

I was thinking to keep an opened socket connection from the device to the server and send receive raw bytes in some custom format.
Is it a good approach and what problems might I run into? What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: have you tried xmpp, and what type of server side scripting do you have??

Comment: No I haven't. Is it available on Android or I have to port some library? I have php scripts on the server side.

Comment: okay. I'll post you an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to message passing, the time needed to initialize a new connection between the server and the client usually exceeds by far the time needed to sent the data itself - at least for simple status-like messages. This adds significantly to the communication latency, which seems to be your main concern.

There are two main ways to deal with this issue:

- *Keep a connection open between both ends at all times:* This is the standard way of dealing with this issue - it has the advantage of programming simplicity *but* you may need to use stay-alive packets regularly to keep the connection open. This may reduce the battery life of a mobile device and increase the networking cost slightly. It may also interact unfavorably with the power-management features of a mobile device.

  In addition, no matter what you do, you cannot *completely* eliminate the possibility of a new connection needing to be established at an inconvenient time - connections that are mostly idle do not fare very well in today's networking infrastructure, I'm afraid...
- *Use a connection-less protocol, such as UDP:* This solution has the potential to minimize the communication and power cost, *but* it requires that your server and client are designed to handle the inherent unreliability of such protocols.

That said, I would not consider the actual format of the data a major concern, until some profiling demonstrates that a custom format will indeed result in significant savings. I would consider the ability to use off-the-shelf network monitoring and analysis software far more important during the development phase...

Answer (score 1):

Push technology is loosely called Comet. The basic logic is to open an persistent HTTP connection with the server (often called HTTP Streaming). As this connection will not last forever (due to the limitations on the server by default), you should be able to reopen the connection. I am not sure how to do it in android specifically but this should be possible.

The basic concept behind this is explained in this [blogpost](http://deepusnath.ning.com/profiles/blogs/comet-a-server-side-push-ajax-explained)

As this is a concept, it can be implemented in any server side programming language of your choice. This [tutorial](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) gives a fair introduction about how to implement COMET in php. [socket.io](http://socket.io) is another such library if you are comfortable with javascript. This SOF [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824604/online-tutorials-for-implementing-comets-server-push) provides some useful links.

Coming to advantages and disadvantages,

1. If you want almost instant updates, COMET is the best.
2. If you have a limit on the number of connections to the server at a time, then COMET probably has to be thought upon based on the tradeoff.